# Core Data add new entity post related to fetchRequest result

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, relationship

I have two Entities in my CoreData model, "Valla" and "Dagbok", these are related with a many-to-many relationship.

When i add a new post to the Dagbok-entity i want it to relate to posts from Valla-entity that i store in an NSArray from a FetchRequest.

The code right now just adds a post to Dagbok

```
- (void)initDagbokDBWithText:(NSString *)text header:(NSString *)header degree:(int)degree weather:(NSString *)weather farg:(NSString *)farg
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dagbok" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newDagbok = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    //NSRelationshipDescription *dagbokRelation = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
    //NSRelationshipDescription *vallaRelation = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];

    [newDagbok setValue:text forKey:@"text"];
    [newDagbok setValue:header forKey:@"header"];
    [newDagbok setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:degree] forKey:@"degree"];
    [newDagbok setValue:weather forKey:@"weather"];
    [newDagbok setValue:farg forKey:@"colorCode"];

    NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Whoops : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

How do i add related objects from an array with fetchRequest results?

Answer (score 0):

Life will be much easier if you create NSManagedObject sub classes to represent your entities rather than dealing with NSManagedObject directly.  Do this by adding a name for your class in the model (the "class" property of the entity), e.g. for Valla set to VallaEntity.  Then XCode  can autogenerate these classes which will then have properties and methods to simplify your code, e.g.

```
DagbokEntity *newDagbok = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

newDagbok.text = text;
newDagbok.header = header;
newDagbok.degree = [NSNumber numberWithInt:degree];
newDagbok.weather = weather;
newDagbok.colorCode = farg;
[newDagbok addVallas:[NSSet setWithArray:arrayOfRelatedVallas]];
```